# C# consume Angular 4 class

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

hou would i consume the following request in my C# web Api.

Here is my Request:

```
this._http.post(
      this.url + 'api/Test',
      { auth: this.authClass},
      { headers: this.header }
    ).map(
      (res) => res.json()
      ).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log("VALUE RECEIVED: ", res);
      })
```

Here is my AuthClass:

```
export class Auth{
    username:string = "";
    password:string = "";
}
```

I have the same class in c# and need to know how do i go about receiving the class as a whole in c#.

I tried:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult login(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
   var jsonString = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<auth>(jsonString);
   return Ok();
}
```

My problem is that it can't parse the json to auth. My json string getting send currently looks like this.

```
{
   "auth": {
       "username": "admin",
       "password": "admin1"
   }
}
```

If its just

```
{
   "username": "admin",
   "password": "admin1"
}
```

then it works without any problems. But i need it to consume the first json example

Comment: haven't use angular 2, but you can post the object directly, not warpped by another property like this: 
    post(
        this.url + 'Auth/register',
        this.regClass
    )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> about receiving the class as a whole in c#.

You wouldn't get the *class*. The recommended wire transfer is `JSON` and it will just give you the Object properties.

## More

Lookup JSON serialization. The internet is full of examples with C# + AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Arno,

You should receive a json object in your web api method.

Then use Json.Net to convert your json object to the C# object you desire.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was to wrap the auth class inside another class.

```
public class authReq
{
    public auth request { get; set; }
}

public class auth
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

And then i deserialize the authReq like so.

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<register>(jsonString);
```